# error in function follow /unfollow users

Tags: php, mysql

hi am working on a script to allow users to follow each other but the action.php file to do the work is giving me a headache or maybe i don't know what and where i a have gone wrong i have 3 functions
-check_count checks if the user is already following another user
-follow_user executes the follow a user query
-unfollow_user executes the unfollow user query

then, i have the action php file that gets ids from the follow and unfollow links

```
//home page
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-body">
<?php
$users = show_users();
$following = following($_SESSION['login']);
if (count($users)){
foreach ($users as $key => $value){
echo $key," ", $value;
if(in_array($key, $following)){
echo " <small><a href='action.php?id=$key&do=unfollow'>unfollow</a>  </small>","<br>";
}else{
echo " <small><a href='action.php?id=$key&do=follow'>follow</a> </small>","<br>";
                                    }
                                }
                            }else{
                               echo "<p>","<b>","There are no users in the system","<b>","<p>"; 
                            }
                            ?>


                            </div>
                        </div>
//action .php file
<?php
```

session_start();
//session variables goes down here

include_once('includes/dbconnect.php');
include_once('functions.php');

$id = $_GET['id'];
$do = $_GET['do'];

switch ($do){
    case "follow":
        follow_user($_SESSION['login'],$id);
        $msg = "You have followed a user!";
    break;

```
case "unfollow":
    unfollow_user($_SESSION['login'],$id);
    $msg = "You have unfollowed a user!";
break;
```

}
$_SESSION['message'] = $msg;

header("Location:home.php");
 ?>

```
 //the functions
 function check_count($first,$second){
    global $conn;
    $sql="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM following WHERE fuser_id='$second' AND follower_id='$first'";
    $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
    return $row[0];
}

function follow_user($me,$them){
    global $conn,$id;
    $count = check_count($me,$them);
        if($count==0){
            $sql="INSERT INTO following (fuser_id,follower_id) VALUES($them,$me)";
            $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        }

}

function unfollow_user($me,$them){
    global $conn,$id;
    $count = check_count($me,$them);
        if($count !=0){
            $sql="DELETE FROM following WHERE fuser_id='$them' and follower_id='$me' limit 1";
            $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        }

}
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: The session message that says you have follow a user and u have unfollowed a user are shown but the users are not added into the following table

Comment: So you see both messages output at the same time?

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: not all messages at the same time but, each message for each case i.e follow and unfollow

Comment: thanks @tadman i gotta keep that in mind my problem is solved